# Alternative position of script that needs to come after specific HTML element?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Sorry I couldn't articulate my question accurately.

I have a jQuery script that needs to be placed below the HTML element it is applied to and not in the head. IE 6 and IE 7 are generating operation aborted message since the script is not a directly child of Body tag. This seems to be a well known bug on IE.

I do not have the privilege to keep the script tag as a direct child of Body tag. Either it should be inside

tag or it should be in the head. If I have it in the head, it obviously doesn't trigger since it should be below the HTML element it is applied to.

What are my options in this case?

Thanks!

Comment: Not sure I understand...why can't you place the jquery in $(document).ready? Maybe you should show some code.

Comment: Thanks! I don't know how I completely missed that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put it in the head, and move your code inside a document.ready handler, like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    // your code here
});
```

This way, your code will only run after the full HTML has been parsed.

Answer (score 1):

You can write the code within head...Just need to write it inside the document ready block, so that it gets executed only after your DOM is ready..

$(document).ready(function(){.....your code......}

Hope that helps. Thank you.

Comment: In case, you want to wait for the complete page to load, you can even write the code inside window.onload blovk...like waiting for iframes, images to load, etc